# Get click outside of DisplayAlert

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have this: `var display = await DisplayAlert("My title", "My question text?", "Yes", "No");`

If I click outside the Display, the default return will be `false`

Is there anyway to get another return if I click outside the display? Like `null`

Answer (score 1):

DisplayAlert is a simple Yes or No tool. Pressing YES means take an action, pressing NO (or maybe outside of the Alert box as a Cancel move) means do not take an action, from the user point of view. (You can't even press outside the box in IOS).

From technical point of view, when the confirmation box pops you can no longer interact with any other objects in the screen besides that confirmation box, until it is closed. And there are no overloads for the method that catches NOT ANSWERED situation. Creating such an overload is out of the scope and I think it is unnecessary.

Simply use DisplayActionSheet if you need more interaction.

Comment: I'll try to use DisplayActionSheet

Comment: @ReinaldoPeres Now you resolve your problem using DisplayActionSheet?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I really needed to get this action. But I talked to the client and I got another way, thanks!

Comment: @ReinaldoPeres please share your solution here, it is helpful to others who face the same problem.